# Obtaining data from table based on checkbox values

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["erp"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string intero = "Select * from judete";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(intero, con);

        SqlDataReader rdr;

        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {


            CheckBoxList check = new CheckBoxList();
            check.Visible = true;

            check.Text = rdr[1].ToString() + "<br/>";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(check);


        }
```

I have the above code that brings up data from table **"Judet"** and for each row a `checkbox`. Now I want when I check a checkbox say USA I want to bring data from another table **"Localitati"** that will display cities from USA.How can I do that? I'm using `c#` in an `asp.net` application.

Comment: Use `Ischecked` property of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnCheckedChanged event for checkBox.....

CheckBox on an ASP.NET Content Form like

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkTest" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkTest_CheckedChanged" />
```

In code behind, keep the following code:

```
protected void chkTest_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do action here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...    
string sqlStatement = "Select * from Localitati";
if (cbUS.IsChecked)
{
sqlStatement += " WHERE country = 'USA' ";
}
else if (cbOtherCountry.IsChecked)
{
sqlStatement += " WHERE country = 'OtherCountry' ";
}
```

Comment: but in my example how can I assign names to checkboxes?

Comment: in asp.net its the ID of the element
<asp:Checkbox ID="cbUSA" />

Comment: yes I know..but I am creating it dynamic so how do I assign the name for each checkbox?